# how can i get multi order by in one table

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

i wanna get the five of the four columns with the highest value in the table.(sorry, pool english, google translate)

nodejs, sequelize, postgresql
i tried to select 20 rows and order by it try to get each highest value top 5 but faild. order by can't performed exactly what i want, only worked in the first order others failed

```
select * from page_item_detail as detail group by detail.id, detail.like,
detail.collection, detail.share, detail.discuss ORDER BY detail.like DESC,
detail.collection DESC, detail.share DESC, detail.discuss DESC limit 20
```

i expect to get data like this

```
like: [top five highest value],
collection: [top five highest value],
share: [top five highest value],
discuss: [top five highest value],
```

sequelize function better, or sql language.
thanks a lot~

Comment: Your best bet is to turn this into 4 sql statements (one for each top 5 column you are after) and run them each separately.

Comment: ok!is that use sequelize.query(`sql language`) to get result or use sequelize.findAll() 4 times?

Comment: I can speak on how to best do that with sequelize since I'm not terribly familiar with it. From a SQL standpoint it would be 4 separate statements, so however that translates into sequelize...

Comment: ok,good.thanks man~